# flutter error when running the app app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: flutter

I have a huge project built with flutter, I left the project for a couple of days, Now when I try  to run the app I face this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Problems reading data from Binary store in C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle7134895285543263727.bin offset 373739 exists? true

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to flutter clean,
flutter pub cache repair,
even removing the flutter version and reinstall it again. And did not work.
Any solution except creating a new project, because I have a lot of implementation.

my Flutter version is 1.22.6
sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

flutter run --verbose:

````
[  +81 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] 9b2d32b605630f28625709ebd9d78ab3016b2bf6
[   +1 ms] executing: [C:\Users\mrabi\fvm\default/] git tag --points-at HEAD
[  +82 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at HEAD
[        ] 1.22.6
[   +9 ms] executing: [C:\Users\mrabi\fvm\default/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +55 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\Users\mrabi\fvm\default/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +50 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +85 ms] executing: [C:\Users\mrabi\fvm\default/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +52 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +85 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +27 ms] executing: C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +54 ms] List of devices attached
           5200e3d5f0466523       device product:j6ltecis model:SM_J600F device:j6lte transport_id:1
[   +9 ms] C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 5200e3d5f0466523 shell getprop
[ +132 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +158 ms] Found plugin connectivity at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-0.4.9+5\
[   +9 ms] Found plugin connectivity_for_web at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity_for_web-0.3.1+4\
[   +7 ms] Found plugin connectivity_macos at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity_macos-0.1.0+7\
[   +8 ms] Found plugin device_info at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\device_info-1.0.0\
[  +17 ms] Found plugin firebase_analytics at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics-6.3.0\
[   +6 ms] Found plugin firebase_analytics_web at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics_web-0.1.1\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin firebase_core at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.5.3\
[   +5 ms] Found plugin firebase_core_web at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core_web-0.2.1+1\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin firebase_messaging at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-6.0.16\
[   +9 ms] Found plugin flutter_device_locale at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_device_locale-0.4.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin flutter_image_compress at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_image_compress-0.7.0\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin flutter_local_notifications at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_local_notifications-1.5.0+1\
[   +6 ms] Found plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.11\
[   +7 ms] Found plugin flutter_uploader at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_uploader-1.2.1\   
[   +3 ms] Found plugin geolocator at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator-6.2.1\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin geolocator_web at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_web-1.0.1\       
[   +3 ms] Found plugin get_version at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\get_version-0.2.2\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin google_maps_flutter at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-0.5.33\
[   +5 ms] Found plugin image_picker at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.6.7+22\
[  +10 ms] Found plugin location at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location-3.2.4\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin location_web at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location_web-1.0.1\
[   +6 ms] Found plugin package_info at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\package_info-0.4.3+4\
[   +7 ms] Found plugin path_provider at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.6.28\        
[   +2 ms] Found plugin path_provider_linux at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_linux-0.0.1+2\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin path_provider_macos at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_macos-0.0.4+8\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin path_provider_windows at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_windows-0.0.4+3\
[   +5 ms] Found plugin permission_handler at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-5.1.0+2\
[  +11 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_linux at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_linux-0.0.2+4\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_macos at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_macos-0.0.1+11\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_web at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_web-0.1.2+7\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_windows at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_windows-0.0.2+3\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin sms_autofill at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sms_autofill-1.3.1\
[   +8 ms] Found plugin store_redirect at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\store_redirect-1.0.2\
[  +10 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.7.10\
[  +22 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_linux at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_linux-0.0.1+4\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_macos at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_macos-0.0.1+9\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_web at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_web-0.1.5+3\ 
[   +2 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_windows at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_windows-0.0.1+3\
[ +123 ms] Found plugin connectivity at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-0.4.9+5\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin connectivity_for_web at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity_for_web-0.3.1+4\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin connectivity_macos at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity_macos-0.1.0+7\
[   +6 ms] Found plugin device_info at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\device_info-1.0.0\
[  +15 ms] Found plugin firebase_analytics at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics-6.3.0\
[   +6 ms] Found plugin firebase_analytics_web at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics_web-0.1.1\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin firebase_core at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.5.3\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin firebase_core_web at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core_web-0.2.1+1\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin firebase_messaging at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-6.0.16\
[   +8 ms] Found plugin flutter_device_locale at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_device_locale-0.4.0\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin flutter_image_compress at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_image_compress-0.7.0\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin flutter_local_notifications at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_local_notifications-1.5.0+1\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-1.0.11\
[   +5 ms] Found plugin flutter_uploader at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_uploader-1.2.1\   
[   +3 ms] Found plugin geolocator at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator-6.2.1\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin geolocator_web at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_web-1.0.1\       
[   +1 ms] Found plugin get_version at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\get_version-0.2.2\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin google_maps_flutter at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-0.5.33\
[   +9 ms] Found plugin image_picker at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.6.7+22\
[   +5 ms] Found plugin location at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location-3.2.4\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin location_web at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location_web-1.0.1\
[   +7 ms] Found plugin package_info at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\package_info-0.4.3+4\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin path_provider at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.6.28\        
[   +2 ms] Found plugin path_provider_linux at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_linux-0.0.1+2\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin path_provider_macos at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_macos-0.0.4+8\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin path_provider_windows at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_windows-0.0.4+3\
[   +5 ms] Found plugin permission_handler at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-5.1.0+2\
[  +10 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences-0.5.12+4\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_linux at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_linux-0.0.2+4\
[   +5 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_macos at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_macos-0.0.1+11\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_web at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_web-0.1.2+7\
[   +1 ms] Found plugin shared_preferences_windows at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_windows-0.0.2+3\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin sms_autofill at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\sms_autofill-1.3.1\
[   +4 ms] Found plugin store_redirect at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\store_redirect-1.0.2\       
[   +7 ms] Found plugin url_launcher at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.7.10\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_linux at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_linux-0.0.1+4\
[   +2 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_macos at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_macos-0.0.1+9\
[   +3 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_web at C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_web-0.1.5+3\ 
[   +1 ms] Found plugin url_launcher_windows at
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher_windows-0.0.1+3\
[  +35 ms] Generating C:\a
projects\develop-v1-pure\waddini\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +31 ms] ro.hardware = samsungexynos7870
[  +51 ms] Starting incremental build...
[   +3 ms] Initializing file store
[  +14 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[   +6 ms] complete
[   +5 ms] Launching lib\main.dart on SM J600F in debug mode...
[   +8 ms] C:\Users\mrabi\fvm\default\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --disable-dart-dev
C:\Users\mrabi\fvm\default\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\windows-x64\frontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
C:\Users\mrabi\fvm\default\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/ --incremental --target=flutter
--debugger-module-names --experimental-emit-debug-metadata -Ddart.developer.causal_async_stacks=true --output-dill
C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.cb8bd1c6\flutter_tool.2dcffc35\app.dill --packages .packages -Ddart.vm.profile=false 
-Ddart.vm.product=false
--bytecode-options=source-positions,local-var-info,debugger-stops,instance-field-initializers,keep-unreachable-code,avoid-closure-call-instructions --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --filesystem-scheme org-dartlang-root --initialize-from-dill
build\cache.dill.track.dill
[  +21 ms] executing: C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 5200e3d5f0466523 shell -x logcat -v time -t
1
[ +185 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 5200e3d5f0466523 shell -x logcat -v
time -t 1
[   +1 ms] --------- beginning of main
           07-07 16:39:04.349 D/BoundBrokerSvc(13990): onUnbind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.measurement.START
           pkg=com.google.android.gms }
[   +2 ms] executing: C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 5200e3d5f0466523 shell -x logcat -v time -t 
1
[ +188 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 5200e3d5f0466523 shell -x logcat -v
time -t 1
[   +2 ms] --------- beginning of main
           07-07 16:39:05.202 D/bauth_FPBAuthService( 3064): FPBAuthService, 11288
[  +24 ms] <- compile package:waddini/main.dart
[  +27 ms] executing: C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[  +49 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 31.0.2-7242960
           Installed as C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[   +3 ms] executing: C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +48 ms] Building APK
[  +27 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +4 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[   +6 ms] Using gradle from C:\a projects\develop-v1-pure\waddini\android\gradlew.bat.
[   +2 ms] C:\a projects\develop-v1-pure\waddini\android\gradlew.bat mode: 33279 rwxrwxrwx.
[  +21 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[ +140 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[        ] openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174, mixed mode)
[   +4 ms] executing: [C:\a projects\develop-v1-pure\waddini\android/] C:\a projects\develop-v1-pure\waddini\android\gradlew.bat     
-Pverbose=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm -Ptarget=C:\a projects\develop-v1-pure\waddini\lib\main.dart
-Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug
[+55447 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +3 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +1 ms] Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
[   +1 ms] > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
[   +1 ms]    > Problems reading data from Binary store in C:\Users\mrabi\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle12309172077266440599.bin offset
373739 exists? true
[   +1 ms] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with
--scan to get full insights.
[   +2 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[   +2 ms] BUILD FAILED in 55s
[ +572 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 56.2s)
[   +7 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 57,921ms.
[   +6 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:607:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
           #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
           #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #18     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #19     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #20     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
           #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #26     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #27     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #34     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)


[ +267 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 257ms
[   +2 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +1 ms] Shutdown hook priority 4
[   +3 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +3 ms] exiting with code 1```
````

Comment: Try cleaning the temp folder on your machine.
Press `WIN+R` and type `%temp%`. Select everything and delete it permanently using `SHIFT+DEL`. You might get some notices about folders not being deleted, just skip them.

Make sure this file is deleted: `gradle7134895285543263727.bin`

Comment: I have tried this now, it still the same